# How to retain base class field values after Deserialization?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, deserialization

I have a class "Employee" which inherits from an abstract base class "Person". I am serializing Employee class in client and sending it to a wcf service which processes Employee record and returns me the Employee object.

But we have this odd requirement because of which the Employee class on the service side is not inherited from "Person" and Employee is just a single entity. For this reason, I have marked all fields of Person as "NonSerialized()" in client (I don't want to send unnecessary fields to the wcf service).

In client, I want to deserialize Employee json object into existing Employee class (which inherits from Person) but the catch is, I want to do it without losing existing field values of abstract base class "Person" in Employee object.

After deserializing the employee json object, I successfully get all values of Employee object but all existing fields of "Person" class become null. I am using Microsoft's "DataContractJsonSerializer" for deserialization. Any help is appreciated.

Below is the code in client:

```
//Creating employee initializes fields of Person class to some values    
var employee = new Employee();

//Code here to call WCF and get response back
DeserializeResponse(out employee, jsonResponse);


private TContract DeserializeResponse<TContract>(out TContract dataContract, string jsonResponse)
            where TContract : class, new()
        {     
            var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TContract));
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response)))
            {
//employee loses all the Person values after deserialization here
                dataContract = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ms) as TContract;
            }       
            return dataContract;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Employee` class is a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) in .NET. Setting `dataContract = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ms) as TContract;` will change the reference held by `dataContract`, pointing to a new memory location. Your old object is gone at that point.

A better option might be to have a `SetPersonDefaults` method on the `Person` base class which you can call in the constructor as well as on the `employee` object after you've deserialized the data.

```
//Creating employee initializes fields of Person class to some values    
var employee = new Employee();

//Code here to call WCF and get response back
DeserializeResponse(out employee, jsonResponse);

employee.SetPersonDefaults();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up using Newtonsoft Json.net library for deserialization as it retains the base class field values unlike DataContractJsonSerializer.